# VS 2017 не компилирует код от VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Если сунуть проект созданный в VS 2015 и установить platform toolset 141 (родной для VS 2017), то компилируется нормально.

Если создать проект с нуля прямо в VS 2017 то выдаёт ошибку.
Если в настройках проекта установить platform toolset 140 (VS 2015) то всё компилируется отлично.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Проект в VS 2017 имеет опцию совместимости. Её нужно отключить. Параметры проекта - C/C++ - Язык - Режим совместимости

Comment: Что тут сказать, оно не работает. Какой вопрос такой и ответ, ни описания что за проект, какие ошибки, никакой информации, тут надо шамана вызывать.

Comment: Ответ следует публиковать именно как ответ, а не дописывать его в вопрос. Откатил последнюю правку.

Comment: @ArtemRachmaninov ответы действительно стоит публиковать в виде ответов, а не в виде правки вопроса